# Output value of HTML element by assigning

Tags: javascript, html

I did button tutorials and HTML Selector tutorials and just cannot seem to get this to work. Please do not just give me the answer, I want to realise my mistake.

Here is my code:

#### Goal

The goal is to take each `<li>` tag and assign a button to them that outputs their text to the Javascript console. As if to say, you have clicked this button therefore you've selected Pants.

#### JS

```
list[x].innerHTML += ('<button onClick="console.log('+list[x].innerHTML+');">Select Item</button>');
```

```js
let storedListValue = [];
let y = 0,
  x = 0;

function outputTargetValues() {
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  console.log(list.length);
  while (x < list.length) {
    storedListValue.push(list[x].innerHTML);
    console.log(storedListValue[x] + " This is storedListValue Data");
    //console.log(list[x].innerHTML);
    list[x].innerHTML += ('<button onClick="console.log(' + list[x].innerHTML + ');">Select Item</button>');
    //console.log(list[x]);
    y++;
    x++;
  }
}

function output(itemName) {
  console.log(itemName);
}

function callMeOutput() {
  console.log(y);
  return storedListValue[x];
}
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li id='i1'>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li id='i2'>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>

<button onClick="outputTargetValues();">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the text of the list element when you click on your first button, you need to change this line:

```
list[x].innerHTML += ('<button onClick="console.log(\'' + list[x].innerHTML + '\');">Select Item</button>');
```

The problem with your code, was that the output of your result was like `console.log(Mens Shirt)`, which is a syntax error. With the code that I provided now the string has quotes so there's no error.

```js
let storedListValue = [];
let y = 0,
  x = 0;

function outputTargetValues() {
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  console.log(list.length);
  while (x < list.length) {
    storedListValue.push(list[x].innerHTML);
    console.log(storedListValue[x] + " This is storedListValue Data");
    list[x].innerHTML += ('<button onClick="console.log(\'' + list[x].innerHTML + '\');">Select Item</button>');
    y++;
    x++;
  }
}

function output(itemName) {
  console.log(itemName);
}

function callMeOutput() {
  console.log(y);
  return storedListValue[x];
}
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li id='i1'>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li id='i2'>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>

<button onClick="outputTargetValues();">Test</button>
```

I recommend that you inspect your HTML output when you get an error like this and try to see if there's any syntax error. This might help you in your future projects :)

Comment: Ehh... Thanks.. was looking for tips, but that helps. So what is that? I see you added `\''` and `\'`

Comment: OHHHHHH. Omg... I totally missed that.. I've been through this code soo many times and it was a simple syntax typo... blehh..

Comment: Its a single quote, I added it with the backslash `\ ` so I could use it inside of the string. You can get more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Comment: I could not really inspect this code, due to my college only letting me run the code in their online ide or Code Editor.. whatever they called it.. Thanks so much though...

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is this line `button onClick="console.log(' + list[x].innerHTML + ')`. `onclick` expect a function name , but you are trying to run a javascript code here.

Secondly always avoid writing inline javascript.

You also need to attach `eventlistener` to the `buttons`, you can do that only after the buttons are created and added to the dom.

In this code snippet the event listener to the `button` are added after the while loop.

Also t

```js
let storedListValue = [];
let y = 0,
  x = 0;
document.getElementById('otTargetVal').addEventListener('click', outputTargetValues)

function outputTargetValues() {
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  while (x < list.length) {
    storedListValue.push(list[x].innerHTML);
    //using template literals and dataset to store the value
    console.log(storedListValue[x] + " This is storedListValue Data");
    list[x].innerHTML += `<button data-val ='${list[x].innerHTML}'>Select Item</button>`;
    y++;
    x++;
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(this.dataset.val)
    })
  })
}

function output(itemName) {
  console.log(itemName);
}

function callMeOutput() {
  console.log(y);
  return storedListValue[x];
}
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li id='i1'>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li id='i2'>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="otTargetVal">Test1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the console parameter with quotes. You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allows embedded expressions and more simple and easy to use. I will also suggest you to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when the value is text as it is more faster and reliable.

Change

```
('<button onClick="console.log(' + list[x].innerHTML + ');">Select Item</button>');
```

To

```
`<button onClick='console.log("${list[x].textContent}")'>Select Item</button>`
```

```js
let storedListValue = [];
let y = 0, x = 0;

function outputTargetValues(){
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  console.log(list.length);
  while(x < list.length){
    storedListValue.push(list[x].textContent);
    console.log(storedListValue[x] + " This is storedListValue Data");
    var v = list[x].textContent;
    list[x].innerHTML += `<button onClick='console.log("${v}")'>Select Item</button>`;
    y++;
    x++;
  }
}
function output(itemName){
  console.log(itemName);
}

function callMeOutput(){
  console.log(y);
  return storedListValue[x];
}
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li id='i1'>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li id='i2'>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>

<button onClick="outputTargetValues();">Test</button>
```